# What is the difference between Metapackage and SDK in .NET Core 2.2?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, .net-core, nuget

I am trying to make distinction between these two concepts in .NET Core terminology. I will try to illustrate my confusion with an example.

When I create a new class library project (eg: `dotnet new classlib -o myclasslib`) the generated `.csproj` file looks like this:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

So far so good. Now, if I try to add WebApi controller class in this project (eg. for the purpose of dynamically loading plugins in my main WebApi application created as: `dotnet new webapi -o mywebapi`) I would need to use things like [ControllerBase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase?view=aspnetcore-2.2) class and `[ApiController]` and `[HttpGet]` attributes. To keep things simple I just derive MyController from ControllerBase like this:

```cs
using System;

namespace myclasslib
{
    public class MyController : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ControllerBase
    {
    }
}
```

Trying to build this with `dotnet build` I get error:

> error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'AspNetCore' does not exist
>   in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

That's kind of expected because I created classlib project, but if change SDK in .csproj to `Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web"` and also change `TargetFramework` to `netcoreapp2.2` (hoping to resolve the reference to [ControllerBase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase?view=aspnetcore-2.2) class) like this:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

I get the same error when building the project. Isn't SDK supposed to include everything I need to build the project?

If I create usual webapi project (eg. `dotnet new webapi -o mywebapi`) the generated `.csproj` looks like this:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design" Version="2.2.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I notice the SDK is same as the one I set, but there is also a metapackage added: `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />`

So why do we need to explicitly add metapackage if we already specified that we want to use Microsoft.NET.Sdk.**Web**?

One additional question: what version of metapackage is used if we don't specify one in PackageReference (like in this generated webapi .csproj)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The SDK is just the build tooling and the .NET Core framework itself. ASP.NET Core is a set of NuGet packages. Essentially .NET Core framework != ASP.NET Core code. The concept of metapackages is only tangentially related. What could be called "ASP.NET Core" is actually dozens of individual NuGet packages. You *could* reference each individually, but as you can imagine, that would be both tiresome and error prone. Metapackages are essentially a NuGet package that depends on multiple other NuGet packages.

By pulling in just the metapackage, therefore, essentially all of that metapackage's dependencies are *also* pull in. As a result, you can simply add a package reference for `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` and you're off to the races. However, the downside to that is that you're potentially getting dependencies that you don't actually need. That's not that big of an issue with something like a web app, because the dependencies can be trimmed, but a class library should not have excess dependencies. As such, you should only reference individual NuGet packages you actually need from the `Microsoft.AspNetCore` namespace.